# python3.4 failed to import gi

Tags: linux, python

I have tried many ways to install gi on my Mint17.02.

```
zen@zen:~ > sudo pip3 install gi
zen@zen:~ > sudo python3.4 -m pip install gi
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gi in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from gi)

zen@zen:~ > sudo python3.4
Python 3.4.3 (default, Sep  2 2015, 01:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39
    print url
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Comment: If you broke your system by installing python 3.4.3 in `/usr/bin`, install it somewhere else first then reinstall the system packages `python3` and `python3-gi`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have compiled your own python (as my Linux Mint 17.2 has 3.4.0 as default python3.4. The easiest way to run programs using `gi` on that installation is to install the package `python3-gi` and symlink the gi directory to the `lib/python3.4/site-packages` directory of your self-compiled python.

You can do so by going the `site-packages` directory of your **3.4.3** install and do:

```
ln -s $(    /usr/bin/python3 -c "import os, gi; print(os.path.dirname(gi.__file__))") .
```

If you are using virtualenvs and/or tox, you should consider making the package(s) you develop dependent on my [`ruamel.venvgtk`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.venvgtk) which does setup those links on installation (including the ones for gtk in case your use pip for python2)

Comment: The source for ruamel.venvgtk is hosted on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/venvgtk), the installed package is empty. All the logic is in its `setup.py`

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me on my elementary os, `redshift-gtk` would not launch anymore because python3 imported gi from `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`, and would fail with that `print url` error.

Uninstalling gi using pip3 fixed the issue for me:

```
$ sudo pip3 uninstall gi
```

From then, python3 imports the "right" gi.